# How to return number of week dynamic in LINQ SQL C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a record(week and year) as well these have data in the database record, want to do the same using LINQ statement on query inside my method on controller. How do I create a dynamic query for these record?. The record(year and week) they return random values and not in sink with the record from the database table. How can I achieve this dynamically? Do I create a parameter to get values back dynamic?

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IList<ExtractionViewModel> GetExtractionViewModels()
        {
            ProductionManagementEntities db = new ProductionManagementEntities();
    
            var scheduleList = (from p in db.ProductionDays
                                from m in db.Models
                                from mx in db.Models
                                from mb in db.Models
                                from ml in db.Models
                                join w in db.Weeks on p.WeekId equals w.WeekId
    
                                orderby w.Year ascending
                                orderby m.Name ascending
                                where (m.InActive == true)
                                where (mx.InActive == false)
                                where (mb.InActive == false)
                                where (ml.InActive == false)
                               
            // how to get a year back in linq and week?
    
                                select new ExtractionViewModel
                                {
    
                                    Year = w.Year,
                                    Week = w.WeekNum,
                                    Day = p.ProductionDate,
                                    VW250 = m.Name,
                                    VW270 = mx.Name,
                                    VW2502PA = mb.Name,
                                    VW270PA = ml.Name
    
    
                                }).ToList();
           
            return scheduleList;
        }
    
        // Model
        public class ExtractionViewModel
        {
            public string Year { get; set; } // how to get this back to linq stament?
    
            public int Week { get; set; } // How to get this back on linq statement?
    
            public DateTime Day { get; set; }
    
            public string VW250 { get; set; }
    
            public string VW270 { get; set; }
    
            public string VW2502PA { get; set; }
    
            public string VW270PA { get; set; }
        }
    
    // SQL Query
    SELECT TOP (1000) [ModelId]
          ,[Name]
          ,[Code]
          ,[CreatedDate]
          ,[CreatedBy]
          ,[ModifiedDate]
          ,[ModifiedBy]
          ,[InActive]
      FROM [ProductionManagement].[Schedule].[Model]

SELECT TOP (1000) [WeekId]
      ,[WeekNum]
      ,[Year]
      ,[CreatedDate]
      ,[CreatedBy]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
      ,[ModifiedBy]
      ,[InActive]
  FROM [ProductionManagement].[Schedule].[Week]
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

BTW. You need to use using with the db context. For example:

```
using var db = new ProductionManagementEntities();
```

---

I think the query you're looking for is something like the following.
You haven't showed us the model or the sql you used and this is a guess..

```
 var scheduleList = (from p in db.ProductionDays
                     join w in db.Weeks on p.WeekId equals w.WeekId
                     join m in db.Models on m.? equal p.? // TODO
                     orderby w.Year ascending
                     orderby m.Name ascending
                     where (m.InActive == true)
                     select new ExtractionViewModel
                     {
                                    Year = w.Year,
                                    Week = w.WeekNum,
                                    Day = p.ProductionDate,
                                    VW250 = m.VW250,
                                    VW270 = mx.VW270
                     }).ToList();
```

Comment: i have and its called "ExtractiobViewModel"

Comment: please have a look at the sql queries for two tables.